# Does a user password protect against network attacks, or only physical?

Tags: passwords, linux

If I create a user in a Linux system with an empty password, does that expose any remote vulnerabilities, or is it only a problem if someone gains physical access to the machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I create a user in a Linux system with an empty password, does that expose any remote vulnerabilities, or is it only a problem if someone gains physical access to the machine?

It does not expose a remote vulnerability, it is considered a misconfiguration which depends on:

1. Your SSH configuration. Per default `PermitEmptyPasswords` is set to `no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
2. How the user itself is configured. If the user is allowed shell access or not which can be seen in `/etc/passwd`.

Assuming that both 1 and 2 apply, you need console (physical) access to your machine in order for this user to be able to login.

There should only be one reason for not setting a user's password and that's when public key authentication is configured. To avoid any confusion, there is a difference between user accounts (uid >= 1000) and service accounts (uid < 1000).

Answer (score 0):

If you allow this user access via **ssh** or **ftp**, this can be definitely a problem.